# Whether we can construct a triangle with half of $-1$ and half of $1$ and satisfies certain properties

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

Suppose we have a pascal-like triangle $A_{i,j}$ with $1\le i\le j\le n$ filled with all $1$ and $-1$, satisfying $A_{i,j}A_{i,j+1}A_{i+1,j+1}=1$ for $1\le i\le j\le n-1$. Also, we are given $n$ id modulo $3$ or $0$ modulo $4$, so the total magnitude of the triangle, $n(n+1)/2$, is even. Will there be a triangle with half $-1$ and half $+1$?

For example, the following triangle with $n=12$ satisfies.

$$-------+--+-\\++++++--+--\\+++++-+--+\\++++---+-\\+++-++--\\++--+-+\\+-+---\\---++\\++-+\\+--\\-+\\-$$

My attempt: Notice that if the first line is $--+$ repeating, then every row is $--+$ repeating, and about $2/3$ of the triangle is $-$. So, If I let first half of them are same and last half be $--+$ ish, then as the pattern about, $3/4$ of the ares is $--+$ repeating-ish, and we have half of the triangle is $-$ and half of the triangle is $+$. Therefore, I tried to repeat the pattern above, but it is unable for me to repeat easily... The first rows of small $n$'s that has this pattern-ish is

$n=3$: $---$

$n=4$: $--++$

$n=7$: $-----+-$

$n=8$: $-----++-$

$n=11$: $------++-+-$

$n=12$: $-------+--+-$

$n=15$: $--------+-++-++$

$n=16$: $---------+--+--+$

$n=19$: $----------+--+--+-+$

$n=20$: $---------+--+--+-+-+$

P.S. I have found the source, it is the 101st problem in *One Hundred Problems in Elementary Mathematics* by Hugo Steinhaus.

Comment: So after the P.S. I think you have found also [this thesis "Steinhaus Triangles" by Núria Pascual Miranda](https://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2117/82029/memoria.pdf?sequence=6&isAllowed=y).

Comment: And ["Solution of Steinhaus's Problem with Plus and Minus Signs" by Harborth (1972)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316572900398/pdf?md5=83bfe8da954063fbdfe812370de72862&pid=1-s2.0-0097316572900398-main.pdf).